# Number of times two charachters appear between two strings, only 1 function, and only parameters are the 2 strings

Tags: python

I want to count the number of times both `a` and `b` occur, in both strings together, using recursion in Python.

For example, if the input was `('aabb', 'bbba')`, the output would be `(3,5)` because there are three `a`'s and five `b`'s total.

What I have tried:

```py
def counting(string1, string2):
   
    if not string1:
        return 0
    elif string1[0]=='a':
        return 1+counting(string[1:],string2)
    else:
        return counting(string[1:],string2)
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

You can recurse until both strings are empty.

```
def counting(string1, string2):
    if string1 or string2:
        a, b = counting(string1 and string1[1:], string2 and string2[1:])
        count = lambda x: (string1 and string1[0] == x or 0) + (string2 and string2[0] == x or 0)
        return (a + count('a'), b + count('b'))
    return (0, 0)

print(counting('aabb', 'bbba'))
```

Comment: This seems to be throwing an error when I run it with string1 and string2 being of different lengths

Comment: @ShubhamPeriwal I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def counting(string1, string2):
  def counting_recurse(string_total):
    if not string_total:
      return (0, 0)
    elif string_total[0]=='a':
      a_count, b_count = counting_recurse(string_total[1:])
      return (1+a_count, b_count)
    elif string_total[0]== 'b':
      a_count, b_count = counting_recurse(string_total[1:])
      return (a_count, b_count +1 )
    else:
      return counting_recurse(string_total[1:])
  return counting_recurse(string1 + string2)
```

This works on your example. Does this solve your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a simpler solution

#### Explanation

- If you've reached end of string, then return (0,0) for a count and b count
- Otherwise, you add 1 + a_count if first character is `a` otherwise you add 0 + a_count.
- Similarly, you add 1 + b_count if first character is `b` otherwise you add 0 + b_count.

a_count is defined as the first value in tuple(), b_count is the second value()

```
def counting_recurse(combine_string):
    if not combine_string:
        return (0, 0)


    return (int(combine_string[0]=='a') +counting_recurse(combine_string[1:])[0], 
        int(combine_string[0]=='b') +counting_recurse(combine_string[1:])[1])

string1 = 'aabb'
string2 = 'bbba'
counting_recurse(string1+string2)
```

#### Output

```
(3, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def counting(stri, char):
   if len(stri) == 0:
      return 0
   elif stri[0] == char:
      return 1 + counting(stri[1:], char)
   else:
      return counting(stri[1:], char)
def count(str1, str2):
   return (counting(str1,'a'),counting(str2,'b'))
print("aabb","bbba")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like having two strings as arguments to the function is unnecessarily complicated, since you count across both strings anyway. So why not simply define the recursive function for a single string and call it on the concatenation of the two strings you're interested in, e.g.

```py
def count_ab(s):
    if not s:
        return 0, 0
    first_a = int(s[0] == 'a')
    first_b = int(s[0] == 'b')
    further_a, further_b = count_ab(s[1:])
    return first_a + further_a, first_b + further_b

count_ab('aabb' + 'bbba')
```

```
(3, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```python
def non_recursive_imp2(*args: str) -> tuple:
    sargs = tuple(map(str, args))
    a_count = 0
    b_count = 0
    for sarg in sargs:
        for ch in sarg:
            if ch == "a":
                a_count += 1
            elif ch == "b":
                b_count += 1
    return (a_count, b_count)

import operator
def recursive_count(inpuht:str, _:str):
    inpuht += _
    if len(inpuht) < 2:
        if inpuht == "a":
            return (1, 0)
        elif inpuht == "b":
            return (0, 1)
        return (0, 0)
    else:
        left_str  = inpuht[:len(inpuht)//2]
        right_str = inpuht[len(inpuht)//2:]
        left_count  = recursive_count(left_str, "")
        right_count = recursive_count(right_str, "")
    return tuple(map(operator.add, left_count, right_count))
```

However, it is easier to write code for a non-recursive implementation:

#### NON-RECURSIVE IMPLEMENTATIONS:

```python
def non_recursive_imp(x:str, y:str) -> tuple:
    merged = x + y
    a_count = 0
    b_count = 0
    for ch in merged:
        if ch == "a":
            a_count +=1
        elif ch == "b":
            b_count +=1
    return (a_count, b_count)
```